# object form.value is empty for the first time

Tags: html, forms, angular6, components

I have a problem with Angular 6:
I'm creating a series of custom components (that represents the input component). The component templates are very simple (they only offer some additional functionality). The problem is this:
each component is associated with a `value` value (using 2-way binding with the `[(ngModel)]` ): this is for example the string, if the component is textual, the item selected if the component is a combo box etc...
If I create a form to sending the various values of the components, like that:

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">

    <my-component name="name" ngModel>
    </my-component>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```

in the component that uses the form, the method `onSubmit(value)` is this:

```
onSubmit(value){
   console.log(value);
}
```

even if a component has a default value selected, when the page is loaded, 
if I click on the Submit button, the result is **always**:
{name: ""}
even if associated with that component there is a value!!
As soon as I change the component interacting with it, everything works.
I tried everything (updating the `value` value of the component in each life cycle method -Lyfecycle Hooks-; updating the value inside the component that uses the form etc..) but I'm not getting any results!
How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) example.

Comment: I'll put it in a moment

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-omkn6t?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-select%2Finput-select.component.html

This is the example. I ask you to try it using the bootstrap-select library, 
otherwise the value selected in <option> will not be interpreted